# Como Ler e imprimir String com espaço em c++?

Tags: c++, string, struct

Até consegui fazer o meu programa ler a String (nome de uma pessoa) com espaço no C++. Porém, na hora de imprimir só retorna o primeiro nome da pessoa como no meu programa abaixo.

//Escrever um programa que cadastre o nome, a matrícula e duas notas de vários alunos. Em seguida imprima a matrícula, o nome e a média de cada um deles.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <new>
using namespace std;


struct cadastro{
  char nome[100];
  int matricula;
  float nota1,nota2;
  float media;
};

int main() {

 
  int i, qtdeAlunos=3;
  cadastro a1[3];

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
      cout<<"\nInsira seu nome: ";
      //scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", a1[i].nome);
      cin>>a1[i].nome;
      //getline( cin, a1[i].nome );
      //cin.ignore();
      cin.ignore(100,'\n');
      cout<<"\nInsira sua matricula: ";
      cin>>a1[i].matricula;
      cout<<"\nInsira sua primeira nota: ";
      cin>>a1[i].nota1;
      cout<<"\nInsira sua segunda nota: ";
      cin>>a1[i].nota2;
    } 
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
      cout<<"\nNome: " << a1[i].nome;
      cout<<"\nMatricula: " << a1[i].matricula;
      cout<< "\nSua media é: " <<(a1[i].nota1+a1[i].nota2)/2;
    }
     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para ler e imprimir Strings em C++, você pode usar a função [getLine](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline), um exemplo de uso(baseado no seu caso) seria:

```
// Lendo Strings
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct cadastro{ char nome[100]; int matricula; float nota1,nota2; float media; };

int main() {

  cadastro a1[3];

  cout<<"\nInsira seu nome: ";
  cin.getline( a1[0].nome,sizeof(a1[0].nome) );
  cout<< a1[0].nome;


}
```

Este código está disponível para testes [aqui](http://cpp.sh/8uiyu).